# Can sentence vary non-primary stress?

Tags: stress

Can the number and position of non-primary stresses vary depending on the sentence it appears in?

E.g. assuming the word *catastrophe*, in RP, has a stress on the second syllable

/kəˈtastrəfi/

Can we sometimes stress the 2nd and 3rd, sometimes the 2nd and 4th, and sometimes just the 2nd? Depending on the sentence it appears in.

Comment: What do you mean by "stress", if not word stress?

Comment: uhh maybe it's peculiar to scansion

Comment: Like in poetry? Or are you talking about prosody in spontaneous speech? Can you give an example of where else you think it might be stressed, and in what context?

Comment: i didn't mean to be asking just about poetry

Comment: Oh, OK. The word "scansion" suggests the topic of poetry. You can stress words differently in poetry, but that's just artistic license.

Comment: Do you mean "When i say a word, am I allowed to put the stress on a different syllable than usual?".  If so then yes, it's a free country, you can pronounce it however you want.  It will tend to sound odd though.

Comment: i'm not sure poetry is "artistic license". i'm interested in isochrony is why i ask

Comment: In that case, do you mainly want to know about the duration of the syllables?

Comment: no, when they are said

Comment: Certainly the stresses, tones, and timings placed on individual syllables change as the context of the word changes, though most people are quite unaware of this, except perhaps when it is done for emphasis.  (But the sentences would sound weirdly mechanical if this was not done.)

Comment: One of the things that can reduce the number of syllables (and therefore stressed syllables) is using long stress groups: ***He's** a **doc**tor, **He's** a good **doc**tor, **He's** a very good **doc**tor,  **He's** an extremely good **doc**tor*, all said in the same amount of time (English is stress-timed). Naturally, this results in many fewer stresses.

Comment: If you have a word with secondary stress on the last syllable, like [catastrophe](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catastrophe), whether you put secondary stress on that syllable can depend on whether the next syllable in the sentence is stressed. For example, you probably wouldn't put much stress on *-phe* in *"The ca**tas**trophe **hap**pened last **night**"*, but you might in *"The ca**tas**tro**phe** in the **arc**tic"*. But you wouldn't change the position of any secondary stress.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; this is unsurprisingly called secondary stress.

From [Teflpedia](http://teflpedia.com/Word_stress):

> **Secondary stress**
>
> Long words may have an extra stress, the second most stressed syllable
>   in the word.
>
> The secondary stress is marked with a small lowered vertical line
>   preceding the stressed syllable: information /ˌɪnfərˈmeɪʃən/,
>   understand /ˌʌndərˈstænd/, represent /ˌreprɪˈzent/.
>
> Words with secondary stress are pronounced as if they were two
>   different words, and one of them has the primary stress: infor-mation,
>   under-stand, repre-sent. If a word has two secondary stresses it is
>   pronounced as three small words: onomatopoeia /ˌɒnəˌmætəˈpiːə/
>   ono-mato-poeia; heterosexuality /ˌhetərəˌsekʃuːˈælətɪ/
>   hetero-sexu-ality.

Comment: the question has been altered so it's not what i was asking

Answer (score 1):

> Does the sentence change the position and number of stresses in a word?

Stress is primarily a function of the word.  Specifically, the meaning of the word.  The sentence simply helps us decode which meaning the word represents.

> There are many two-syllable words in English whose meaning and class change with a change in stress. The word present, for example is a two-syllable word. If we stress the first syllable, it is a noun (gift) or an adjective (opposite of absent). But if we stress the second syllable, it becomes a verb (to offer). More examples: the words export, import, contract and object can all be nouns or verbs depending on whether the stress is on the first or second syllable.
>
> [englishclub: word stress rules](https://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/word-stress-rules.htm)

Stress can also be a function of who is speaking.

> For a few words, native English speakers don't always "agree" on where to put the stress. For example, some people say teleVIsion and others say TELevision. Another example is: CONtroversy and conTROversy.
>
> [englishclub: word stress rules](https://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/word-stress-rules.htm)

Context can make a difference.  Such as when you're stressing every syllable for someone who's having trouble hearing you.

---

> Can we sometimes stress the 2nd and 3rd, sometimes the 2nd and 4th, and sometimes just the 2nd?

Depends what you mean by and.  At the same time in the same word?  No.

> One word has only one stress. (One word cannot have two stresses. If you hear two stresses, you hear two words. Two stresses cannot be one word. It is true that there can be a "secondary" stress in some words. But a secondary stress is much smaller than the main [primary] stress, and is only used in long words.)
>
> [englishclub: word stress rules](https://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/word-stress-rules.htm)

However, there is certainly no rule that says stress must always be on the 1st syllable.

And indeed, you can put the stress anywhere, [just to be silly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1VwYp0cbDU).

Comment: This idea that the secondary stress is ***much*** smaller than the primary stress sounds like you're reading websites written by U.K. speakers (and checking, indeed you are). In AmE, secondary stresses can be quite large (e.g., *military*).

Comment: @Peter Shor Here too. The statement is too sweeping.  I'd go so far as to say that there are words with double primary stress; _decontamination_ at the very least can come close.

Answer (score 0):

There are many two-syllable words stressed on the *first* syllable for a ***noun*** usage, or on the *second* syllable for the ***verb*** sense...

**ad**dress *noun – the location of a building*
ad**dress** *verb – to write down an address OR to speak to a group of people*
**com**pound *noun – something made of two or more parts*
com**pound** *verb – to combine or add*
**con**test *noun – a game or event of competition*
con**test** *verb – to challenge or dispute*
**con**tract *noun – a written agreement*
con**tract** *verb – to make smaller in size*
etc., etc.

I got that list from [this Wordpress blog](https://pronunciationcoach.wordpress.com/category/word-stress/). I can think of one case where the shift is from noun (a**rith**metic) to adjective (arith**met**ic), and there's also **u**nionized (labour relations; *organised into a union*) and un**i**onized (chemistry; *not ionised*). Offhand though, I can't think of any word where the meaning changes according to the *number* of stressed syllables.

As @Peter points out below, there are cases such as *Rainier* (the mountain) with two syllables, where *rainier* (more rainy) has three syllables. But those are really two different words with different origins, rather that the same word with different meanings according to enunciation.

---

But I get the impression OP is actually asking if he can "creatively" vary stress patterns in order to effect a change in meaning. To a first approximation I'd have to say *No, you **can't** do that!*

Dictionary pronunciation guides excepted, we don't normally indicate the stress orthographically, so you'd need to be in a spoken medium anyway - and unless your audience were primed to expect "meaningfully non-standard delivery" (a poetry reading from a respected writer, perhaps), they'd probably just assume you weren't a very competent speaker.

Comment: I'm taking up your implicit challenge. *Rainier* (the mountain) has two syllables, while *rainier* (meaning more rainy) has three syllables.

Comment: @Peter: ty - I knew I could count on *someone!* (as also implied, I'll add that to the answer). But as with *unionized*, we're talking about two *different words* - what I'd really like is an example where it's essentially *the same word* (manifestly having the same etymology, at the very least). I think it's quite possible there are such words. I recall arguing with my English teacher as a teenager I because I thought 3-syllable *caTHOLic* meant "diverse", as opposed to 2-syllable *CAtholic* being "of the RC church". I lost the argument, obviously, but I still wish I'd been right!

Comment: _Beloved_ is usually pronounced with 2 syllables as the attributive adjective and often with 3 as the noun. [Will Styler](http://linguisticmystic.com/2012/11/22/on-the-pronunciation-of-beloved-and-giving-thanks/) comments.

Comment: i'm not sure if you (or anyone) really answered this question. i'm not asking if i can vary the stress patterns of words as i choose, but whether *non-primary stress* can vary according to the sentence